# Draw contiguous circles with random radiuses

Tags: geometry, pascal

Well I have to generate 10 random radiuses and then draw circles. But I'm not sure how to calculate X coordinate so they will be contigous. I got this code but it doesn't work properly

```
uses graphabc;
var
a: array [1..10] of integer; 
i, x, y, r, rn: integer;
begin

i:=1;
while (i < 11) do begin
  rn:= random(5,50);
  a[i]:=rn;
  i:=i+1;
end;

r:=a[1];
y:=300;
x:=100;


for i:=1 to 10 do begin
  circle(x, y, r);
  r:=a[i];
  x:=x+r;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: *... but it doesn't work properly* is a rather useless description of a problem. Please clarify, what do you expect and what happens instead? Be precise, please.

Comment: @TomBrunberg it gives me next result [link](https://imgur.com/IhI0Sku)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make two circles to touch each other, distance  between centers must be sum of both radiuses. Simple correction (remove `if i > 1` if shift is needed):

```
for i:=1 to 10 do begin
  r:=a[i];
  if i > 1 then
      x:=x+r;
  circle(x, y, r);
  x:=x+r;
  end;
end.
```